# How to set upload_handlers on a per-request basis using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF view where I need to ensure that uploaded files land on the filesystem and not just in memory. [DRF respects Django's `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS` setting](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser), but I don't want to change it for my whole app, just this one view.

I know that in a regular Django view I could set `request.upload_handlers` to my desired value, but that doesn't seem to work in DRF. I've tried doing it from `.initialize_request()` in my viewset, like so:

```
def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.upload_handlers = ["django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler"]
    return super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

but I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: You cannot set the upload handlers after the upload has been processed.
```

What is the correct way for me to set the upload handlers for a single DRF view (in particular, the `create` action of a generic viewset)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are not assigning the upload handler in the ***right way***

```
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import TemporaryFileUploadHandler
from rest_framework import viewsets


class MyUploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # your view class attributes goes here....
    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.upload_handlers = [TemporaryFileUploadHandler(request)] # initialization goes here
        return super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### Note

This will work *as-is* in all DRF class based views